# Alternativa para padding-nevative em tabela

Tags: html, table, uitableviewcell, css-padding

Tenho uma tabela, onde preciso diminuir o `padding` das linhas da mesma.

Se eu pudesse utilizar um `padding-bottom: -XXpx; e padding-top: -XXpx;` resolveria meu problema. Porém, não é possível utilizar valores negativos, até onde minha pesquisa informou.
Gostaria de saber se realmente não é possível utilizar um valor negativo? Se sim, qual a alternativa para diminuir o espaçamento entre as linhas de uma tabela.

Um pequeno exemplo da tabela seria esse:

```css
 .tblCompleta tr td {
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:1149px;" id="tblPrestacao" class="table-striped cell-border table-bordered tblCompleta table-responsive" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr bgcolor="#F1F1F1">
                                            <th><p align="center">Entidade</p></th>
                                                <th bgcolor="#F0E68C"><p align="center">1</p></th>
                                                                                        <th bgcolor="#F0E68C"><p align="center">2</p></th>
                                                                                        <th bgcolor="#F0E68C"><p align="center">3</p></th>
                                                                                        <th bgcolor="#F0E68C"><p align="center">4</p></th>
                                                                                        <th bgcolor="#F0E68C"><p align="center">5</p></th>
                                                                                        <th bgcolor="#F0E68C"><p align="center">6</p></th>
                                                                                        <th><p align="center">7</p></th>
                                                                                        <th><p align="center">8</p></th>
                                                                                        <th><p align="center">9</p></th>
                                                                                        <th><p align="center">10</p></th>
                                                                                        <th><p align="center">11</p></th>
                                                                                        <th><p align="center">12</p></th>
    
                                            <th><p align="center">Pendência</p></th>
                                            <th><p align="center">Observação</p></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
        <tr>
                       <td style="width: 400px;" >
                    <font size="2">
                        <a class="btnEditCliente" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/Cliente/EditarCliente/3" title="Editar Cliente">C.M. Areal</a>
                    </font>
                </td>
    
            
    
                <td bgcolor="gren">
                    <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJaneiro é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p>
                </td>
    
            
                <td bgcolor="gren">
                    <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bFevereiro é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p>
                </td>
            
                <td bgcolor="gren">
                    <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMarco é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p>
                </td>
            
                <td bgcolor="red"><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAbril é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td bgcolor="red"><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMaio é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJunho é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJulho é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAgosto é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bSetembro é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bOutubro é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bNovembro é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bDezembro é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
            <td align="center" style="width: 20px">
    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TipoPendencia must be a number." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.TipoPendencia"><option value="1">Cliente</option>
    <option value="2">Produto</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">N/A</option>
    </select>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 210px">
                <p align="center">N/A</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                       <td style="width: 400px;" >
                    <font size="2">
                        <a class="btnEditCliente" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/Cliente/EditarCliente/5" title="Editar Cliente">P.M. Guapimirim</a>
                    </font>
                </td>
    
            
    
                <td bgcolor="red"><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJaneiro é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td bgcolor="red"><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bFevereiro é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
            
                <td bgcolor="red"><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMarco é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
            
                <td bgcolor="red"><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAbril é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td bgcolor="red"><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMaio é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJunho é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJulho é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAgosto é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bSetembro é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bOutubro é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bNovembro é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bDezembro é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
            <td align="center" style="width: 20px">
    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TipoPendencia must be a number." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.TipoPendencia"><option selected="selected" value="1">Cliente</option>
    <option value="2">Produto</option>
    <option value="3">Servi&#231;o</option>
    </select>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 210px">
                <p align="center">N/A....</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           
                <td style="width: 400px;" >
                    <font size="2">
                        <a class="btnEditCliente" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/Cliente/EditarCliente/4" title="Editar Cliente">C.M. Guapimirim</a>
                    </font>
                </td>
    
            
    
                <td bgcolor="red"><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJaneiro é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td bgcolor="red"><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bFevereiro é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
            
                <td bgcolor="red"><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMarco é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
            
                <td bgcolor="red"><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAbril é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td bgcolor="red"><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMaio é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJunho é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJulho é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAgosto é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bSetembro é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bOutubro é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bNovembro é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bDezembro é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
            <td align="center" style="width: 20px">
    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TipoPendencia must be a number." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.TipoPendencia"><option value="1">Cliente</option>
    <option value="2">Produto</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">Servi&#231;o</option>
    </select>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 210px">
                <p align="center">N/A ....</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           
    
                <td style="width: 400px;" >
                    <font size="2">
                        <a class="btnEditCliente" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/Cliente/EditarCliente/6" title="Editar Cliente">Inst. Previd&#234;ncia Iguaba Grande</a>
                    </font>
                </td>
    
            
    
                <td bgcolor="gren">
                    <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJaneiro é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p>
                </td>
    
            
                <td bgcolor="gren">
                    <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bFevereiro é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p>
                </td>
            
                <td bgcolor="red"><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMarco é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
            
                <td bgcolor="red"><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAbril é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td bgcolor="red"><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMaio é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJunho é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJulho é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAgosto é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bSetembro é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bOutubro é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bNovembro é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
                <td><p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bDezembro é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></p> </td>
    
            
            <td align="center" style="width: 20px">
    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TipoPendencia must be a number." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.TipoPendencia"><option value="1">Cliente</option>
    <option value="2">Produto</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">Servi&#231;o</option>
    </select>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 210px">
                <p align="center">N/A</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

**Resumindo:** Como diminuir o espaço entre a texto e as margens da linha em uma tabela?

Segue um pequeno exemplo, porém que ilustra bem o que estou tentando dizer.

[Exemplo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4a05y2m/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você precisa zerar os elementos herdeiros dentro das tags.

Aconselho você estudar mais `CSS` isso são coisas básicas.

***Veja o exemplo abaixo:***

```css
tr,
td,
p {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  border: 0 !important;
}
select {
  height: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:1149px;" id="tblPrestacao" class="table-striped cell-border table-bordered tblCompleta table-responsive" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#F1F1F1">
      <th>
        <p align="center">Entidade</p>
      </th>
      <th bgcolor="#F0E68C">
        <p align="center">1</p>
      </th>
      <th bgcolor="#F0E68C">
        <p align="center">2</p>
      </th>
      <th bgcolor="#F0E68C">
        <p align="center">3</p>
      </th>
      <th bgcolor="#F0E68C">
        <p align="center">4</p>
      </th>
      <th bgcolor="#F0E68C">
        <p align="center">5</p>
      </th>
      <th bgcolor="#F0E68C">
        <p align="center">6</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p align="center">7</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p align="center">8</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p align="center">9</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p align="center">10</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p align="center">11</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p align="center">12</p>
      </th>

      <th>
        <p align="center">Pendência</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p align="center">Observação</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 400px;">
        <font size="2">
                        <a class="btnEditCliente" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/Cliente/EditarCliente/3" title="Editar Cliente">C.M. Areal</a>
                    </font>
      </td>



      <td bgcolor="gren">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJaneiro é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td bgcolor="gren">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bFevereiro é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td bgcolor="gren">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMarco é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td bgcolor="red">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAbril é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td bgcolor="red">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMaio é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJunho é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJulho é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAgosto é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bSetembro é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bOutubro é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bNovembro é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bDezembro é obrigatório." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td align="center" style="width: 20px">
        <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TipoPendencia must be a number." name="[0].EnvioPrestacao.TipoPendencia">
          <option value="1">Cliente</option>
          <option value="2">Produto</option>
          <option selected="selected" value="3">N/A</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 210px">
        <p align="center">N/A</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 400px;">
        <font size="2">
                        <a class="btnEditCliente" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/Cliente/EditarCliente/5" title="Editar Cliente">P.M. Guapimirim</a>
                    </font>
      </td>



      <td bgcolor="red">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJaneiro é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td bgcolor="red">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bFevereiro é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td bgcolor="red">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMarco é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td bgcolor="red">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAbril é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td bgcolor="red">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMaio é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJunho é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJulho é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAgosto é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bSetembro é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bOutubro é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bNovembro é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bDezembro é obrigatório." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td align="center" style="width: 20px">
        <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TipoPendencia must be a number." name="[1].EnvioPrestacao.TipoPendencia">
          <option selected="selected" value="1">Cliente</option>
          <option value="2">Produto</option>
          <option value="3">Servi&#231;o</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 210px">
        <p align="center">N/A....</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td style="width: 400px;">
        <font size="2">
                        <a class="btnEditCliente" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/Cliente/EditarCliente/4" title="Editar Cliente">C.M. Guapimirim</a>
                    </font>
      </td>



      <td bgcolor="red">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJaneiro é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td bgcolor="red">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bFevereiro é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td bgcolor="red">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMarco é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td bgcolor="red">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAbril é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td bgcolor="red">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMaio é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJunho é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJulho é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAgosto é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bSetembro é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bOutubro é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bNovembro é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bDezembro é obrigatório." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td align="center" style="width: 20px">
        <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TipoPendencia must be a number." name="[2].EnvioPrestacao.TipoPendencia">
          <option value="1">Cliente</option>
          <option value="2">Produto</option>
          <option selected="selected" value="3">Servi&#231;o</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 210px">
        <p align="center">N/A ....</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>


      <td style="width: 400px;">
        <font size="2">
                        <a class="btnEditCliente" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="/Cliente/EditarCliente/6" title="Editar Cliente">Inst. Previd&#234;ncia Iguaba Grande</a>
                    </font>
      </td>



      <td bgcolor="gren">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJaneiro é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bJaneiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td bgcolor="gren">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bFevereiro é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bFevereiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td bgcolor="red">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMarco é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bMarco" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>

      <td bgcolor="red">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAbril é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bAbril" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td bgcolor="red">
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMaio é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bMaio" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJunho é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bJunho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJulho é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bJulho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAgosto é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bAgosto" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bSetembro é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bSetembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bOutubro é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bOutubro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bNovembro é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bNovembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>
        <p align="center"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bDezembro é obrigatório." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.bDezembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td align="center" style="width: 20px">
        <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TipoPendencia must be a number." name="[3].EnvioPrestacao.TipoPendencia">
          <option value="1">Cliente</option>
          <option value="2">Produto</option>
          <option selected="selected" value="3">Servi&#231;o</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 210px">
        <p align="center">N/A</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Pode deixar que estou estudando. Porém não havia encontrado nada sobre isso. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.